# Better way to shifting project to Brunch

Tags: brunch

Few days back, I found brunch and I was pretty impressed. It is very good to start a new project. But I have one existing project where I have less, css, javascripts and html. Distributed in folders based on requirement.

Now, it will be tough to get all things converted to coffeescript, less and jade. (I tried that, it is little bit more work than it seems.)

Now, here are the issues I have faced.

Brunch having jade plugin, don't allowed html files to compile and put into public file.

So, I started with dead simple, but couldn't find proper guide to get it up and running and where to put what. If I am putting html file in app, it is not coming to public folder at all.

So, if there is any video or tutorial to get it started from zero, it will be great and more over it is a good idea to move old things to brunch, I pretty like brunch for their bundling things.

Please let me know if any more details required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply copy stuff to public dir, place it to `app/assets`, not `app`.

Comment: okies... That solved the html issue. Can you point out few articles or video's for getting started.

Comment: the getting started video will be there soon